# Differences between Email-to-Case and On-Demand Email-to-Case

Tags: email, servicecloud, email2case

I looked up some Salesforce documentation, and I am still a little confused on the differences between Email-to-Case and On-Demand Email-to-Case, as well as when should I implement one or the other.

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customizesupport_email.htm

Based on my understanding, Email-to-Case requires downloading an agent behind your company's firewall (and thus is more secure). Email-to-Case limits customization and custom field mapping, but automatically identifies replies, Contacts, Subjects, and other fields. Email-to-Case also accepts emails larger than 25 MB.

On the other hand, On-Demand Email-to-Case just uses APEX, which allows for more customization and custom field mapping, but only accepts emails less than 25 MB. Likewise, On-Demand Email-to-Case solely uses the Salesforce.com platform, so it is less secure (not behind your company's firewall).

Is my understanding correct? In what situations should I consider using one or the other?

Comment: On-demand email to Case doesn't really "use" Apex - it creates automatically for you a Case + EmailMessage child, assigns the case a threadId, and through the Case Settings and EmailToCase settings, you have various options to play with.  In either model, you can use apex, workflows, processBuilder to respond to DML events in Case and EmailMessage

Comment: Thanks @crop1645! This definitely answers my question and was very helpful.

Comment: Are there any other things that I should consider when implementing either Email-to-Case or On-Demand Email-to-Case? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On-demand email to Case doesn't really "use" Apex - it creates automatically for you a Case + EmailMessage child, assigns the case a threadId, and through the Case Settings and EmailToCase settings, you have various options to play with.

In either model, you can use apex, workflows, processBuilder to respond to DML events in Case and EmailMessage

I personally found On-demand Email-to-case a better solution for our org as I didn't have to involve some other team establishing an EmailAgent on some server. Everything I needed could be done with point-and-click SFDC (except for the autoforwarding rule from the support@mycompany.com to the SFDC-generated on demand email-to-case email address (but my mail system admins could handle this easily)

We dealt with the limits on attachment size by messaging the users on the support web site.

Since we trust Salesforce.com, and we weren't dealing with customer PII or money, the security issues with On Demand Email to case were OK with us

You have located the relevant documentation